# SimpleDateFormat does not throw ParseException

Tags: java

Yesterday I've found strange behavior during code debugging: method parse from SimpleDateFormat class did not throw exception during parsing incorrect date. Following shot groovy script describes problem :

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

SimpleDateFormat sdfOUT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
System.out.print(sdfOUT.parse("2016-04-29"))
```

Instead of throwing throwing ParseException parse method it
returns date : Thu Oct 07 00:00:00 CET 34

Any idea why it's behaves like this ?

Comment: For a strict parsing, use `setLenient(false)` :  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)

Comment: One comment, if you change a little bit a original script